# Custom uses-permission with ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, android-permissions, cordova-android

On app builds with Ionic3 (cordova 7.0.0 | android@6.2.3), I need to use microphone, SIP and internet access (WI-FI).

So I try edit config.xml with edit-config in this way:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" targe="/manifest”>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
</edit-config>
```

but no request is shown. Moreover, I wish that AndroidManifest.xml has more uses-permission keys (one for every request) but the result is one row with only permission for RECORD_AUDIO.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advice for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

To add those permissions you need to use [`<config-file>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/index.html#config-file)  not `<edit-config>`, for example:

```
    <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
    </config-file>
```

But that's not enough on Android 6+ - you need to request [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for [dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous_permissions).

In Cordova you could do this using [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) with [`requestRuntimePermissions()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#requestruntimepermissions), e.g.:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermissions(function(statuses){
    for (var permission in statuses){
        switch(statuses[permission]){
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
                console.log("Permission granted to use "+permission);
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
                console.log("Permission to use "+permission+" has not been requested yet");
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
                console.log("Permission denied to use "+permission+" - ask again?");
                break;
            case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
                console.log("Permission permanently denied to use "+permission+" - guess we won't be using it then!");
                break;
        }
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
},[
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.USE_SIP,
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I add also ionic-native/diagnostic and I check the authorization with getMicrophoneAuthorizationStatus and if is not granted, then I  wish to show request  with requestMicrophoneAuthorization(). Anyway I will try your solution.

Comment: I try your solution and works for half because the fix of config.xml it's ok but the code of cordova.plugins doesn't work. So I use the native plugin of Ionic (ionic-diagnostic) and with this, the request is shown.

Comment: `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` is the global namespace of the plugin in Javascript. However, Ionic is Typescript-based so ionic-diagnostic provides a Typescript wrapper for the plugin's Javascript API.