# How to enable webRTC to InAppBrowser app on Ionic4 for Android and iOS?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, ionic4, inappbrowser

This happens in android and iOS build of ionic v4 app. I need embeb a website from a URL to my app, but this website has a JS plugin to read code bars in real time: https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS, this plugin uses the method "navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia", so I'm using the plugin "InAppBrowser" to embeb this site to the app but this plugin doesn't works on Android or iOS app but if you test it on Chrome or safari browser it works perfectly.

I have given all permissions in config.xml, but still couldn't access the camera. is there anything else needs to be done, for getting camera access for external website?

home.page.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private platform: Platform, private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions, private iab: InAppBrowser) {   

    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
          result => console.log('Has permission?', result.hasPermission),
          err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA)
        );

        this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA]);
      });

      this.iab.create('https://supermercadocomunal.com/tienda/', '_self', 'location=no, clearcache=yes, zoom=no');
    }
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AndroidPermissions,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    InAppBrowser    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

config.xml

```xml
<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <custom-config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.autofocus" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
        </custom-config-file>
    </platform>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.0.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="8.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alfredo Takazu Did you try?

ionic-native/diagnostic and  check the authorization with getMicrophoneAuthorizationStatus

see more
[Custom uses-permission with ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674872/custom-uses-permission-with-ionic-3)